Numpy indexing value picking up rule
Let's suppose a program like this:
x = np.arange(0, 12).reshape(2, 3, 2)
y = x[0:2, [0, 1], 0:2]
print(y.flatten())

This code prints [0 1 2 3 6 7 8 9].
Of course, these each value is extracted from the original ndarray x.
I examined the index of each value in the original x and below is it:
0: x[0, 0, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1: x[0, 0, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
2: x[0, 1, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
3: x[0, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
6: x[1, 0, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
7: x[1, 0, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
8: x[1, 1, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
9: x[1, 1, 1]

Looking at the first 4 lines, x[0, 0, 0] is before x[0, 0, 1]. And after that, x[0, 1, 0] and x[0, 1, 1] is coming.
So "the rule" of the order to pick up the value from x would look like this: First, do loop over the first argument 0:2. Then, in the loop, do inner loop over the second argument [0, 1]. At last, the last loop over the third argument 0:2 happens inside. Pseudo code will look like this:
indices = []
for i in 0:2 { # first arg
    for j in [0, 1] { # second arg
        for k in 0:2 { # third arg
            indices.append([i, j, k])
        }
    }
}

This is also my original understanding of numpy value picking up rule.
But below code looks like not following the rule.
x = np.arange(0, 72).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2]
print(y.flatten())

This code prints [30 31 66 67 32 33 68 69], indices are:
30: x[0, 2, 1, 0, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
31: x[0, 2, 1, 0, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
66: x[1, 2, 1, 0, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
67: x[1, 2, 1, 0, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
32: x[0, 2, 1, 1, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
33: x[0, 2, 1, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
68: x[1, 2, 1, 1, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
69: x[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

If above rule is correct, the psuedo code will look like this:
for i in 0:2 {
    for j in 2 {
        for k in 1:2 {
            for l in [0:1] {
                for m in 0:2 {
                    indices.append([i, j, k, l, m])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

However, the actual result shows that loop over 4th argumens [0, 1] happens after loop over the first argument 0:2. I want to know why this happens.
I think I am missing or misunderstanding something about the numpy advanced indexing rule, but why are there a difference like this?

With advanced indexing like that the y.strides may be different from what you expect. I'd also check y.base

The last example has mixed basic and advanced with a slice the middle.  The unexpected shape is well documented and discussed on SO.

Hi, I checked the base and strides but nothing seems different.



x = np.arange(0, 72).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
y = x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2]
y
array([[[[30,31]],



    [[66,67]]],
    
   [[[32, 33]],
   
    [[68, 69]]]])




y.base
y.shape
(2, 2, 1, 2)
y.strides
(32, 16, 16, 8)




The first case:
In [149]: x = np.arange(0, 12).reshape(2, 3, 2)
     ...: y = x[0:2, [0, 1], 0:2]

strides show how the elements are accessed (in bytes), leftmost largest, and iterates outermost as you tested:
In [150]: x.shape, x.strides
Out[150]: ((2, 3, 2), (24, 8, 4))

y because it has an list index [0,1], has a different stride order, though that doesn't messup the flattening.
In [151]: y.shape, y.strides
Out[151]: ((2, 2, 2), (8, 16, 4))

In [152]: y
Out[152]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[6, 7],
        [8, 9]]])

In [153]: y.ravel()
Out[153]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])

Under the covers numpy has indexed with that [0,1] first, and then transposed to the correct order.  For the most part this is step is transparent to users.
In [154]: y.base
Out[154]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [6, 7]],

       [[2, 3],
        [8, 9]]])

Your second example, has a slice in the middle.  As documented, the slice dimensions are placed last.
In [156]: x = np.arange(0, 72).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
     ...: y = x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2]

In [157]: y.shape, y.strides
Out[157]: ((2, 2, 1, 2), (16, 8, 8, 4))

I think the same thing is happending here as in the first case, but it can (unambiguously) transpose this y.
If I replace the 1:2 slice with a list:
In [158]: x = np.arange(0, 72).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
     ...: y = x[0:2, 2, [1], [0, 1], 0:2]

In [159]: y.shape, y.strides
Out[159]: ((2, 2, 2), (8, 16, 4))

Flattening the 2 cases:
In [160]: x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2].ravel()
Out[160]: array([30, 31, 66, 67, 32, 33, 68, 69])

In [161]: x[0:2, 2, [1], [0, 1], 0:2].ravel()
Out[161]: array([30, 31, 32, 33, 66, 67, 68, 69])

The base for the 'working' case, is the same as for the mixed basic/advanced, except of an extra size 1 dimension:
In [162]: x[0:2, 2, [1], [0, 1], 0:2].base
Out[162]: 
array([[[30, 31],
        [66, 67]],

       [[32, 33],
        [68, 69]]])

In [163]: x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2].base  # pure copy

In [164]: x[0:2, 2, 1:2, [0, 1], 0:2]
Out[164]: 
array([[[[30, 31]],

        [[66, 67]]],


       [[[32, 33]],

        [[68, 69]]]])

The [158] y is the [162] base transposed, much as was done with your first example.
The messed up diemsion order with mixed basic/advanced indexing is more abvious when the resulting shapes are all different.
I could dig up the appropriate documentation section, and some SO deuplicates for this issue.

I see but I still don't understand when and how the transpose happens. Can you explain it or do you know any link yo the dovumentation?

This transpose during indexing is not documented.  It's just evident from the strides and base.

Thank you for your help. I asked a question about this in GitHub issue. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/26321

Apart from the documented mixed indexing, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing, a lot of what I explain might be considered implementation details.
